# php regex to find javascript variables

Tags: php, regex

The text I am searching contains `vars (= OR :) { (the stuff I want }`

Between the = and the { can be only whitespace and may contain a new line.

I will be turning this into a key/value array in PHP.

Here is what I am attempting which does not result in any matches:

```
$str = "vars = {'first' : 'joe', 'last' : 'smith' };";

preg_match("/^vars\s=\s\{(.*)\}/",$str, $matches);

echo $matches[0];
```

another string that should match:

```
$str = "vars : {'first' : 'joe', 'last' : 'smith' };";
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could grab everything inside the { } and then let a JSON parser do the rest for you.

```
$str = 'vars = {"first" : "joe", "last" : "smith" };';
preg_match("/\{.*\}/",$str, $matches);
var_dump(json_decode($matches[0]));

object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["first"]=>
  string(3) "joe"
  ["last"]=>
  string(5) "smith"
}
```

This approach only works with valid JSON ofc.

Comment: You need to escape the `{}` and the `()` is unnecessary.

Comment: i changed the answer. ty.

Answer (score 0):

To match it use:

```
preg_match_all('/^vars\s[=:]\s{(.*)};$/m', $str, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$matches = $matches[0];
```